# Installing FullCalendar in Angular

Tags: angular, installation, calendar, fullcalendar

I am quite confused about installation of Fullcalendar In Angular 8. I have followed the fullcalendar site and installed the package under @fullcalendar (using npm install --save @fullcalendar/angular etc)
However as I was looking for a particular requirement came across some examples that installs the fullcalendar under 'fullcalendar' folder whereas previous one was '@fullcalendar' . SO anyone you has used FullCalendar in Angular project, can you please share your experience and which approach was successful.
As I followed the first approach and tried to have a modal on dateclick(), it doesn't recognizes modal and gives error. SO in order to make it successful, please share the approach that you have been happy with.

Moreover if it is the later approach how do i install 'list' ,'daygrid' etc ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know angular, but are you using the [fullCalendar Angular component](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular), or not? It's a bit unclear, especially due to the lack of any code or error messages in your question.

Comment: Yes I am using Fullcalendar , there is no code to specify as the question is about the approach.

Comment: I know you're using fullCalendar. But are you using the ready-made Angular component for fullCalendar, as per the link I gave? That was my question, specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has specific instructions
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular
for angular along with plugins.

Also, I am using PrimeNg full calendar which internally uses Fullcalendar plugin. Refer
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/fullcalendar